# Getting wp-cli to work on windows

Tags: php, windows, wordpress, wp-cli

I'm trying to get wp cli working on my MAMP setup but the issue i have when browsing to a WordPress setup and running for instance wp -v i get this notice:

```
Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is require
```

d by WordPress.

I have looked arround and saw that is something about the PATH's in windows for PHP but its setup correctly.
This is the user variables for my logged in user on the PC:

```
Variable: PATH
Value: D:\MAMP\wp-cli\;D:\MAMP\bin\php\php5.6.8\
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include both the php folder and the mysql folder in your PATH.
Also, make sure your PATH value doesn't include any spaces and that the different paths are separated by a `;`